# Qt pri files in the cmake world

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I use to split Qt projects in multiple directories which I might call components.
In each folder I put a `.pri` file which refers to that folder `.h` and `.cpp` files.
And I often add a `.pro` file to those components in order to quick build/test/verify only that component (I mean this `.pro` will include only my component `.pri`).

And of course I have the project `.pro` which includes multiple `.pri`. In other words the `.pri`s are used in two contexts, while quick build/test/verify only that particular component and while building the main project.

These days it looks like cmake is getting more popular and I read about it here and there. If move my project to cmake can I still split it in sub folders, have a cmakelists.txt in each folder/component? And have a main cmakelists.txt which refers to the components?

Comment: Short answer: yes, you can do it with cmake.

Comment: I create a hierarchy where there is a CMakeLists.txt in every folder.

Comment: How do you call the sub CMakeLists.txt from the top CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @KcFnMi, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html.

Comment: @KcFnMi, you just include a subdirectory and can refer the target name and actually everything from a subdirectory project. CMake's language is far more richer than qmake's. Convenient settings that you used to place in a pri-file could be defined in a CMake variable, or list. Subprojects also available to see definitions from other subprojects as well as from main CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: But what should be put on the CMakeLists.txt that goes on the sub directory? How to refer to the `.h` and `.cpp` on that folder? Considering I don't want to add_library or add_executable on the sub folder.